# How do you select foreign key rows that do not exist in the parent table in Postgres?

Tags: sql, postgresql, select, foreign-keys, subquery

table2:

```
id (pk)
table1_id (fk)
other_columns
```

table1:

```
id (pk)
other_columns
```

Table 1 records were deleted but the Table 2 references remain and were'nt nullified. How do you best query from Table 2 a list selecting foreign keys that dont exist in Table 1?

Answer (score 3):

If you had cascading foreign key constraints, this would not be an issue.  But you can use `not exists`:

```
select t2.*
from table2 t2
where not exists (select 1
                  from table1 t1
                  where t1.pk = t2.fk
                 );
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `not exists`:

```
select t2.*
from table2 t2
where not exists (select 1 from table1 t1 where t1.id = t2.table1_id)
```

You can easily turn this to a `delete` statement:

```
delete from table 2
where not exists (select 1 from mytable where t1.id = t2.table1_id)
```